getting 403 forbidden when called aws http gateway post api from s3 bucket
I am trying call Lambda endpoint(aws api gateway) through html page which is located in AWS S3 bucket when i am trying to call api i am getting 403 forbidden error. I am using AWS signature for it same call works when tried in postman
here is my javascript code
<script>
    document.getElementById('dialler').addEventListener('click', async e => {

        console.log('clicked');

        e.preventDefault();
        const formElement = document.querySelector('form');
        const formData = new FormData(formElement);
        const telephoneNumber = formData.get('telephone');
        const jsonBody = { TelephoneNumber: telephoneNumber };


        const region = 'XXX';
        const endpoint = 'XXXX/XXX/remove';
        const accessKeyId = 'XXX';
        const secretAccessKey = 'XXXX';

        AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
            region: region
        });

        // Build the request
        const signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint, region), 'execute-api');
        signer.addAuthorization(AWS.config.credentials, new Date());

        // Prepare headers and options for fetch
        const headers = {};
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(signer.request.headers)) {
            headers[key] = value;
            headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/json';
        }

        try {
            // Make the signed API call
            const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headers,
                body: JSON.stringify(jsonBody)
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP Error: ${response.status}`);
            }

            const data = await response.json();
            console.log('API Response:', data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error calling API:', error);
        }
    });
</script>

when i click remove button i am sending telephone number to the api and it gets removed and i am getting response back. here is authorization in http gateway
  HttpApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      CorsConfiguration:
        AllowOrigins:
          - "*"
        AllowHeaders:
          - "*"
        AllowMethods:
          - "*"
        MaxAge: 600
        AllowCredentials: false
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
        EnableIamAuthorizer: true

Also below CORS used in S3 bucket
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Content-Range",
            "Content-Length",
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]

Not getting why forbidden error thrown

Are you sure you're using exactly the same endpoint in both cases? With API Gateway, even adding/missing a "/" can make the API Gateway throw a 403, because it's not a correct path

@Caldazaryes i am using same url as in postman
